# Running a modular Sinatra app with Thin and EventMachine. It starts twice?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, eventmachine, thin

I have a modular Sinatra web app running using Thin, with EventMachine running additional tasks.

It works, but there's something a bit odd about the webserver: Any requests, whether successful or 404s, don't appear in the log output from Thin/Sinatra. And when I cancel the process, the server ends twice.

Here's the rough, basic structure of the app:

Procfile:

```
web: ruby app.rb
```

app.rb:

```
require 'thin'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'app/frontend'

EM.run do
  # Start some background tasks here...

  EM.add_periodic_timer(1200) do
    # Do a repeating task here...
  end

  App::Frontend.run!
end
```

app/frontend.rb:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module App
  class Frontend < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
      # Display page
    end
    # etc
  end
end
```

When I do `foreman start` then I get:

```
16:50:00 web.1  | started with pid 76423
16:50:01 web.1  | [messages about EventMachine background tasks starting]
16:50:01 web.1  | == Sinatra/1.4.3 has taken the stage on 5000 for development with backup from Thin
16:50:01 web.1  | >> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
16:50:01 web.1  | >> Maximum connections set to 1024
16:50:01 web.1  | >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:5000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Nothing more is output when I request existing web pages (which load OK) or not-existing web pages. When I cancel the process I get:

```
^CSIGINT received
16:50:08 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
16:50:08 web.1  | >> Stopping ...
16:50:08 web.1  | == Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
16:50:08 web.1  | >> Stopping ...
16:50:08 web.1  | == Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
16:50:08 web.1  | exited with code 0
```

That Sinatra finishes twice makes me think I'm somehow running it twice, and the one that's serving the web pages isn't being logged... but I don't know how I'm managing this!

Comment: maybe  App::Frontend.run! automagically start EM itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs on Modular vs. Classic style](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Modular%20vs.%20Classic%20Style) mention that there are some changes to the default settings, and one of these is logging, which is turned off by default.

Adding `settings.logging = true` to the top of `class Frontend < Sinatra::Base` gives me a log in my terminal window for the localhost:5000 requests.

I don't *think* the second issue is that it's creating two processes, but rather that it's killing and re-starting the process right before closing the server. This can be solved by following the Sinatra recipe for using EventMachine with Sinatra, which is a little more complicated than what you've done. Here's their code, modified to fit your app:

The new `app.rb`:

```rb
EM.run do
  server  = 'thin'
  host    = '0.0.0.0'
  port    = ENV['PORT'] || '8181'
  web_app = App::Frontend.new

  # Start some background tasks here...

  EM.add_periodic_timer(1200) do
    # Do a repeating task here...
  end

  dispatch = Rack::Builder.app do
    map '/' do
      run web_app
    end
  end

  Rack::Server.start({
    app:    dispatch,
    server: server,
    Host:   host,
    Port:   port
  })
end
```

([original source, from Sinatra Recipes](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/embed/event-machine))

The use of `ENV['PORT']` in the app.rb lets you use multiple instances in foreman (e.g., `foreman start -p 4000 -c web=2`, which will run services on ports 4000 and 4001). And both of them appear in the log!

Hope that helps.

Comment: Brilliant, that all works, thanks acsmith! I must admit, I tried using that example at some point in my experiments but must have screwed something up because I couldn't get it working. Now it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I spoke too soon, just seeing the server working... I still get two `>> Stopping ...` lines when I cancel the process. Not the end of the world, it just feels a bit wrong. Strange.

Comment: Yeah, so do I. Hm. Looking at the activity monitor, it's starting two Ruby processes: 22mb and 10mb. Just running `ruby app.rb` without foreman starts one 22mb process, so it seems like there's only one Sinatra starting, (and only one stops). So it seems that foreman, not EM, is causing this issue. There's not much info on foreman out there...do you know how to get a verbose readout?

Comment: I don't. Strange: You can have foreman run extra processes, so if I do `foreman start -c web=2` it obviously starts two processes... and stopping it then shows `>> Stopping ...` four times, and `exited with code 0` twice.

Comment: But you're right that it seems like foreman doing this. Bypassing it and just running `ruby ahola.rb` directly on the command line starts and stops as you'd expect, starting only one process.

Comment: Yeah, so what I thought might be the case is that foreman was capturing the stdout or stderr or something from Sinatra, and flushing selected parts of it. I think it might just be redundant messaging. If I add the `-c web=2` arg, it launched 3 processes for me, and the lowest PID is one less than the lowest mentioned in `started with pid ####` in the Terminal log. So it looks like the number of processes is correct, but foreman captures logging in a weird way.